# How to iterate through array and show datalist in JSX?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to generate a datalist from an array in React. When I pass in the array I can successfully iterate through it and log the `'city'` value out to the console.

When I perform the same `.map` iteration without JSX the compiler states that `'city'` is undefined

```
class CityList extends React.Component {
    render(props) {
        const cities = this.props.cities;

        cities.map(function(city) {
          console.log(city);
        });

        return (
          <datalist id="cities-list">
            cities.map(function(city) {
              <option value={city}></option>
            });
          </datalist>
        );
    }
}
```

How can I successfully output the value within JSX?

[Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/djflayva/pen/BmBgvN) demonstrating the error.

Comment: can you post the the result of console.log(this.props.cities)

Comment: @LinasMickevicius ["test", "test"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the curly brackets in your JSX around `cities.map`!

https://codepen.io/joepmeindertsma/pen/bYbXrW?editors=0010#0

```
return (
  <datalist id="cities-list">
    {cities.map(function(city) {
       <option value={city}></option>
    })}
  </datalist>
);
```

Comment: true! totally missed it. And the return too should be there.

Comment: Yup, including a return is neater, but it's not required for JSX.

Comment: Good to know, I will keep using it though.

Comment: Ah, so I failed to escape from JSX to JavaScript! Thanks!